# Problems using dataframe in R with columns of different width

Tags: r, rstudio, frame, readfile

I have uploaded a csv file, like the following:

> datamap <- read.csv(file = "TheWorlds50BestRestaurants2018.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

I want to put that dataset into a data frame. However, I have problems with the following sentence

```
mimapa <- data.frame(Year =         datamap$Year,Ranking = datamap$Ranking,
Name = datamap$Name, City = datamap$City, Country = datamap$Country,Latitude = datamap$Latitude,Longitude = c(datamap$Longitude))
```

The error is:

> ```
> Error in data.frame(Year = datamap$Year, Ranking = datamap$Ranking, Name = c(datamap$Name),  : 
>   arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 50
> ```

Please help me with that error,
Thank you.

Comment: `read.csv()` returns a dataframe. No need to convert it to a dataframe again after reading!

Comment: The error probably appears because one of `datamap$Year`, `datamap$Ranking`, `datamap$Name`, ... does not exists in the data.frame `datamap`. Note that R is case sensitive.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)